# Automate Azure VM server SQL job backup copy to another server?

Tags: sql-server, azure, virtual-machine, azure-sql-database

I Have Azure VM server. In that I have a job set up for automatic backup to Azure local storage. I will need to store a copy of that backup in another server? How do I do that? Is there any way to do it automatically?

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT. (I've removed the shouting for you.)

Comment: by server do you mean another cloud VM? Why don't you copy to blob storage instead? Anyway for automation in Azure, look into the Azure component called.... _Azure Automation_. You can write a powershell script to do it. In fact you can probably find a sample that does it for you. Also keep in mind there is all kinds of redundancy and geographic replication going on automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of you can do it directly from one serve to another server but you can do via blob storage. Use AzCopy(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy) for uploading and downloading files from blobs.

Comment: I'm New for Azure cloud server so can you please step by step with Image

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Azure File Service to copy the backups for archival purposes. Use the following commands to mount a network drive to archive the backup:

1. Create a storage account in Windows Azure PowerShell

   New-AzureStorageAccount -StorageAccountName “tpch1tbbackup” -Location “West US”
2. Create a storage context

   $storageAccountName = “tpch1tbbackup”

   $storageKey = Get-AzureStorageKey $storageAccountName | %{$_.Primary}

   $context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageKey
3. Create a share

   New-AzureStorageShare -Name backup -Context $context
4. Attach the share to your Azure VM

   net use x: \tpch1tbbackup.file.core.windows.netbackup /u:$storageAccountName $storageKey
5. Xcopy backup to x: to offload the backup on the mounted drive

   xcopy D:backup*.* X:tpchbackup*.*

Comment: I'm New for Azure cloud server so can you please step by step with Image

Answer (score 0):

According to you question, you can achieve this with many ways. As  [@Alberto Morillo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8184139/alberto-morillo) and [@Vivek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4764055/vivek) said, you can use powershell and AzCopy to do that . But if you want to back up and copy automatically, you can use a **runbook** to achieve that.

Also,  you can set Schedules to runbook. With this, you can backup your resource automatically. Runbook can run powershell cmdlets and provide many features to make your job automatically.

See more details about Runbook in Azure automation in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-starting-a-runbook).

Comment: I'm New for Azure cloud server so can you please step by step with Image

Answer (score 0):

To automate you backup process from one server to another server using azure storage service, you have to make three batch files.

1. It will take backup of your db and will store it locally. here is the command to do that.

set FileName=DBName_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%.bacpac
echo %FileName%
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe" /a:Export /ssn:your IP(00:00:00) /sdn:yourdatabaseName /tf:"D:\%FileName%" /su:username /sp:"password"

2. It will post your locally saved backup file to Azure storage.

   "C:\AzCopy\AzCopy.exe" /Source:D: /Dest:https://youstoragedestination.link/blobname/ /DestKey:yourAzureStoragekey /Pattern:"*.bacpac" /Y
   del "d:*.bacpac"
3. from this batch file call above two batch file 
   example:
   call "yourpath\backupFile.bat"
   call "youpath\backupFilepushing2azure.bat"

you can schedule your third batch file to automate your process.
Now you have pushed your backup file to Azure Storage, which is enough i think.
If you really want to save that backup file to another server then make another batch file that will download your backup file from blob to server using AzCopy.